# Problem viewing rendered output when viewing edits

Tags: support, bug, feature-request

When viewing edits on questions, is there a way to view previous edits exactly how they would have appeared on the main site, with the LaTeX formatted rather than just the original code? I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, my computer isn't formatting the pages properly or if this is just not an option when viewing edits. If the latter, I'd like to make this a feature request.

Using the "show the rendered output with differences and removals" options only renders parts of the question that weren't changed, any LaTeX that was changed is shown unrendered, which sometimes bugs me when I want to see what the question used to look like. This is happening with both chrome and Firefox.

I apologise if this is a simple thing that I'm missing, but I've searched through both main and meta FAQs and done a meta search for this problem, and haven't found anything on it.

Comment: Related: [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits?rq=1) is similar, but not exactly the same because I'm talking about viewing past edits rather than reviewing new ones. It seems like it's a problem with stack-exchange rather than me, if that's the case then what do people think about this as a feature request?

Comment: +1 Your suggestion is missing [an example](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/171822/revisions).

Comment: @MarkHurd Thank you very much, I didn't think to put one in!

Answer (score 1):

Click the "*link*" link, part of the "*source, edit, [rollback,] link*" tools next to the revision number. This gives the permanent link to the older revision, where the entire post can be seen as it used to appear. For example, here is [revision 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/171822/2) of [the example in Mark Hurd's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/171822/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I was reviewing an edit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44748), clicked on "rendered edit" but nothing happened.  I am seeing the $\LaTeX$ but would like to see the result to check.

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than an answer. In fact, it's not really about this question at all, but about the related question linked to in Tom Oldfield's first comment.